# Can apache avro write to network?

Tags: flume, avro

I am trying to write huge amount of logs to hdfs. For that i am using flume with hdfs as sink and avro as source. What i need to do is serialize my logs using avro over the network to my flume. The source of the flume is configured as:

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = avro
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.bind = 0.0.0.0
a1.sources.r1.port = 4141
```

EDIT: fixed code block

Answer (score 0):

Use Flume's [RpcClient](http://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/api/RpcClient.html):

```
RpcClient client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(host, 4141);
client.append(EventBuilder.withBody(message));
client.close();
```